# neither find_all nor find works

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the name of every favorites on the page of a user of our choice. but with this code I get the error "ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'" but if I try to use find it get the opposite error and it ask me to use find_all. I'm a beginner and I don't know what to do. (also to test the code you can use the username "Kineta" she's an administrator so anyone can get access to her profile page).
thanks for your help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

usr_name = str(input('the user you are searching for '))
html_text = requests.get('https://myanimelist.net/profile/'+usr_name)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'lxml')
favs = soup.find_all('div', class_='fav-slide-outer')
favs_title = favs.find_all('span', class_='title fs10')
print(favs_title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program throws exception because you are trying to use `.find_all` on `ResultSet` (favs_title = favs.find_all(...)`,` ResultSet`doesn't have function`.find_all`). Instead, you can use CSS selector and select all required elements directly:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://myanimelist.net/profile/Kineta"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for t in soup.select(".fav-slide .title"):
    print(t.text)
```

Prints:

```
Kono Oto Tomare!
Yuukoku no Moriarty
Kaze ga Tsuyoku Fuiteiru
ACCA: 13-ku Kansatsu-ka
Fukigen na Mononokean
Kakuriyo no Yadomeshi
Shirokuma Cafe
Fruits Basket
Akatsuki no Yona
Colette wa Shinu Koto ni Shita
Okobore Hime to Entaku no Kishi
Meteor Methuselah
Inu x Boku SS
Vampire Juujikai
Mirako, Yuuta
Forger, Loid
Osaki, Kaname
Miyazumi, Tatsuru
Takaoka, Tetsuki
Okamoto, Souma
Shirota, Tsukasa
Archiviste, Noé
Fang, Li Ren
Fukuroi, Michiru
Sakurayashiki, Kaoru
James Moriarty, Albert
Souma, Kyou
Hades
Yona
Son, Hak
Mashima, Taichi
Ootomo, Jin
Collabel, Yuca
Masuda, Toshiki
Furukawa, Makoto
Satou, Takuya
Midorikawa, Hikaru
Miki, Shinichiro
Hino, Satoshi
Hosoya, Yoshimasa
Kimura, Ryouhei
Ono, Daisuke
KENN
Yoshino, Hiroyuki
Toriumi, Kousuke
Toyonaga, Toshiyuki
Ooishi, Masayoshi
Shirodaira, Kyou
Hakusensha
```

---

EDIT: To get Anime/Manga/Character favorites:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://myanimelist.net/profile/Kineta"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


anime_favorites = [t.text for t in soup.select("#anime_favorites .title")]
manga_favorites = [t.text for t in soup.select("#manga_favorites .title")]
char_favorites = [t.text for t in soup.select("#character_favorites .title")]

print("Anime Favorites")
print("-" * 80)
print(*anime_favorites, sep="\n")
print()

print("Manga Favorites")
print("-" * 80)
print(*manga_favorites, sep="\n")
print()

print("Character Favorites")
print("-" * 80)
print(*char_favorites, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
Anime Favorites
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kono Oto Tomare!
Yuukoku no Moriarty
Kaze ga Tsuyoku Fuiteiru
ACCA: 13-ku Kansatsu-ka
Fukigen na Mononokean
Kakuriyo no Yadomeshi
Shirokuma Cafe

Manga Favorites
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fruits Basket
Akatsuki no Yona
Colette wa Shinu Koto ni Shita
Okobore Hime to Entaku no Kishi
Meteor Methuselah
Inu x Boku SS
Vampire Juujikai

Character Favorites
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mirako, Yuuta
Forger, Loid
Osaki, Kaname
Miyazumi, Tatsuru
Takaoka, Tetsuki
Okamoto, Souma
Shirota, Tsukasa
Archiviste, Noé
Fang, Li Ren
Fukuroi, Michiru
Sakurayashiki, Kaoru
James Moriarty, Albert
Souma, Kyou
Hades
Yona
Son, Hak
Mashima, Taichi
Ootomo, Jin
Collabel, Yuca
```

Comment: This is a nice program to accomplish the task the OP is trying to do, but it doesn't answer the problem of the OP's program.

Comment: Nicely done.  +1 from me.

Comment: Just a short question : would it be possible to insert the result that comes from anime favs in a list, the one coming from the favs manga in another list, etc... do you think it would be possible inside of your t loop or do I have to create another loop before to dispatch them before even getting the result. idk if I'm clear enough but if you go take a look at the page I'm using for reference you'll undetstand

Comment: thanks a lot ! I understand how you did it pretty easily, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

find and find_all work you just need to use them correctly. You can't use them to search through lists (like the 'favs' variable in your example). You can always iterate through the lists with for loop and use the 'find' or 'find_all' functions.

I preferred making it a bit easier but you can choose the way you prefer as I am not sure if mine is more efficient:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

usr_name = str(input('the user you are searching for '))
html_text = requests.get('https://myanimelist.net/profile/'+usr_name)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'lxml')
favs = soup.find_all('div', class_='fav-slide-outer')
for fav in favs:
    tag=fav.span
    print(tag.text)
```

If you need more info on how to use bs4 functions correctly i suggest looking through their docks [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

I looked at the page a bit and changed to code a bit, this way you should get all the results you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

usr_name = str(input('the user you are searching for '))
html_text = requests.get('https://myanimelist.net/profile/'+usr_name)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'lxml')
favs = soup.find_all('li', class_='btn-fav')
for fav in favs:
    tag=fav.span
    print(tag.text)
```

I think the problem here is not really the code but how you searched your results and how the site is structured.

Comment: Thanks ! you just changed what had to be, and I see where I was wrong.